# How to keep selected layers on page load in Leaflet?

Tags: leaflet

I have a leaflet map that reload page and map view depending on a drop-down list. I have many layers in it and I'd like to keep selected layers as selected when the page reload after clicking on an item in the drop-down list.

I hope it's clear enough.

Comment: if you mean that a user's selection is 'saved' on page reload, you could use cookies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on your app and your browser requirements, you can use one of these methods:

- Store selected layers in the browser, like session storage (https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage); doesn't work in all browsers
- Store the information in the URL hash - nice if you want users to be able to share links with each other and get to the same state, works in all browsers (an example here: http://cykelbanor.se/ - check the URL changing when you switch layers etc.)
- Store it in a cookie; should also work in all browsers
- Store it on the server